# Trying to make the cmd prompt speak, is givng me an error

Tags: cmd, command, command-prompt

```
#(NewObject -ComObject SAPI.SPVOICE).Speak("we're in")
```

The error is:

> .Speak("we're in") was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues, the first being that the code/command you have provided is incorrect, it has a typo, which I've corrected below:

```
(New-Object -ComObject SAPI.SPVOICE).Speak("we're in")
```

The other issue, and for me, the main issue, is that you've used the following tags, [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), and [command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt), which tells me that you are running your command in the Windows Command Prompt, `cmd.exe`. Your code however is for PowerShell, `powershell.exe`, and should either be run, exactly as above in Windows PowerShell, or as an argument to it in `cmd.exe`, like this:

```batch-file
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(New-Object -ComObject SAPI.SPVOICE).Speak(\"we're in\")"
```

---

If you do not want to see a return value on the screen you could do something like this at the PowerShell prompt:

```
(New-Object -ComObject SAPI.SPVOICE).Speak("we're in") | Out-Null
```

Or:

```
(New-Object -ComObject SAPI.SPVOICE).Speak("we're in") *> $Null
```

In the Command Prompt window, you could redirect the standard output to the NUL device:

```batch-file
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(New-Object -ComObject SAPI.SPVOICE).Speak(\"we're in\")" > NUL
```

Comment: thanks a lot man i really appreciate it 